# Asserting @tailrec on Option.getOrElse

Tags: scala, tail-recursion

In the following, the line `maybeNext.map{rec}.getOrElse(n)` uses the `Option` monad to implement the recurse or escape pattern.

```
scala> @tailrec                                          
     | def rec(n: Int): Int = {                          
     |   val maybeNext = if (n >= 99) None else Some(n+1)
     |   maybeNext.map{rec}.getOrElse(n)                 
     | }
```

Looks good, however:

```
<console>:7: error: could not optimize @tailrec annotated method: 
it contains a recursive call not in tail position
       def rec(n: Int): Int = {
           ^
```

I feel that the compiler should be able to sort out tail recursion in this case. It is equivalent to the following (somewhat repulsive, but compilable) sample:

```
scala> @tailrec                                          
     | def rec(n: Int): Int = {                          
     |   val maybeNext = if (n >= 99) None else Some(n+1)
     |   if (maybeNext.isEmpty) n                        
     |   else rec(maybeNext.get)                         
     | }
rec: (n: Int)Int
```

Can anyone provide illumination here? Why can't the compiler figure it out? Is it a bug, or an oversight? Is the problem too difficult?

Edit: Remove the `@tailrec` from the first example and the method compiles; the loop terminates. The last call is always `getOrElse` which is equivalent to `if option.isEmpty defaultValue else recurse`. I think this could and should be inferred by the compiler.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not a bug, it is not an oversight, and it is not a tail recursion.

Yes, you can *write* the code in a tail recursive manner, but that doesn't mean every equivalent algorithm can be made tail recursive. Let's take this code:

```
maybeNext.map{rec].getOrElse(n)
```

First, the last call is to `getOrElse(n)`. This call is not optional -- it is always made, and it is necessary to adjust the result. But let's ignore that.

The next to last call is to `map{rec}`. *Not* to `rec`. In fact, `rec` is not called *at all* in your code! Some other function calls it (and, in fact, it is not the last call on `map` either), but not your function.

For something to be tail recursive, you need to be able to replace the call with a "goto", so to speak. Like this:

```
def rec(n: Int): Int = { 
  BEGINNING:                         
  val maybeNext = if (n >= 99) None else Some(n+1)
  if (maybeNext.isEmpty) n                        
  else { 
    n = maybeNext.get
    goto BEGINNING
   }                         
}
```

How would that happen in the other code?

```
def rec(n: Int): Int = {                  
  BEGINNING:        
  val maybeNext = if (n >= 99) None else Some(n+1)
  maybeNext.map{x => n = x; goto BEGINNING}.getOrElse(n)                 
}
```

The goto here is *not* inside `rec`. It is inside an anonymous `Function1`'s `apply`, which, by its turn, is inside an `Option`'s `map`, so a branch here would leave two stack frames on each call. Assuming inter-method branching was possible in first place.

Comment: Remove the @tailrec and the method compiles; the loop terminates. The last call is `getOrElse` which is equivalent to `if option.isEmpty defaultValue else goto BEGINNING. I think this could and should be inferred.

Comment: @Synesso (I am pretty sure there is no trivial way to infer such a transformation is all but the most trivial contrived cases. In the post there was a tail-rec *equivalent* posted. Having the scalac compiler try rewrite code to an equivalent that *might* be tail-recursive is arguably outside the scope and a side-effecting language with different compilation modules does not help things. @tailrec just says "ensure this *is* tail-recursive" -- no AI, no gnome in a box.)

Comment: It's a shame because (I think) `map{recursiveCall}.getOrElse(nonRecursiveValue)` is unequivocally logically tail-recursive. And, not allowing this pattern (even if it has to be explicitly enabled in the compiler logic), means people will be dropping the annotation or writing less elegant code.

Comment: @Synesso Write a compiler plugin-in :-)

Comment: @pst ... haha, and then I'll find out just how "easy" it is? :)

Comment: @Synesso Oh, indeed. I was confused there for a moment, but a tail recursion is replacing a function call with a branch at the point it happens, period. To do anything else would require, at the very least, that the Scala compiler know how Option works, and that is something Odersky is very much against. See, for instance, his absolute insistence on not optimizing range for-comprehensions to while loops.

Comment: @Daniel - Eh, did PaulP not get his optimisation for that one into trunk? I know Martin used to be strongly against it, but think the profiling results were fairly hard to argue with.

Comment: @Kevin He never argued the profiling results. He just stood by having optimizations be generic, instead of being specifically targetted at a class. Javap here shows foreach being called.